# Force Alfresco thumbnail creation via REST

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am trying to force the creation of a custom Alfresco content, which contains a image/jpeg.
I create the content with a custom `WebScript`. However, when I try to retrieve the preview, I get an error, as the `Thumbnail was not found`.

The url I use to retrieve the preview is:

```
/alfresco/s/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/<UUID>/content/thumbnails/medium
```

I also append the following parameters:

```
?qc=queue&fc=force
```

to force preview creation on request.
Conversely, when I go to Share, the preview is created in fact the previous url, without the parameters, shows the preview after visiting the content page in Share.
Also, if I use the explicit preview creation service, it works, i.e.:
send a POST request to `/alfresco/s/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/<UUID>/content/thumbnails` with body `{"thumbnailName":"medium"}`.

How can I force the creation of the preview and obtain it with a single service invocation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter to append to the GET request is `?c=force`. This way, the preview is created when it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Below webscript can be used to create thumbnails, if you need a cm:pdf you can replace doclib to pdf. This can trigger the renditions

/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/{$nodeid}/content/thumbnails/**doclib?c=force**